# How to create Unique ID with uniqueidentifier DataType?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uniqueidentifier

I have use Unique UserID in Sql Server with uniqueidentifier DataType.

The following C# code always creates a unique identifier?

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Yes, can this question be closed now?

Comment: why don't you check it by run this code multiple times

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a short answer, but:

Yes, your code always creates a unique identifier.